# How can i set prefix value to upper and lower case? (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

### Heres My Problem

```
const prefix = T!
const realPrefix = prefix.toLowerCase() || prefix;
```

Command is still executing with just "t!".. as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ6a4.png)
but i want that the command should works in both capital (T!) and Small (t!)
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ6a4.png)

Comment: Could you provide your current code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your code looks like but this worked for me! [Here is the Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYUfO.png)

```
client.on("message", message => {
      const prefix = "t!";
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix))
    {
        if(command === "ping") {
          message.channel.send("Pong.")
        }
    }
});

client.login('BOT TOKEN);
```

Comment: Ty for the help br :)) my code is now working very well..

Answer (score 0):

### The Error

The logical OR operator (`||`) will return the value of the first truthy operand. In the example `x || y`, if `x` is truthy, it will return `x`. If `x` is not truthy, it will return `y`.

```js
if (true || true) console.log(1);
if (true || false) console.log(2);
if (false || false) console.log(3);
```

**The only falsey values are `false`, `0`, `null`, `NaN`, `undefined`, and empty strings**. This means that, in your snippet, `prefix.toLowerCase()` will always be truthy (unless `prefix` is an empty string), meaning the `y` operand will never be considered.

---

### The Solution(s)

By far the easiest solution would be to convert the message to lowercase instead of the prefix.

```js
if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('t!')) return;
```

```js
const content = 'T!Hello World';
if (content.toLowerCase().startsWith('t!')) 
 console.log('Hurrah!');
```

The second and a bit more obscure method would be using a regular expression.

```js
if (!/^[tT]!/.test(message.content)) return;

// ^ - this must be the start of the message
// [tT] - this character can either be 't' or 'T'
// ! - this is a character literal (just !)
```

```js
const content = 'T!Hello World';
if (/^[tT]!/.test(content)) console.log('Hurrah');
```